# how to make a input tag takes the rest of a td space in css?

Tags: css

I have 2 tag inside a td

```
<td>
<label>some text</label>
<input type="text"/>
</td>
```

My goal is to not have these 2 tags form 2 rows inside the `<td>`, and the `input` tag takes whatever space `<label>` tag left. How can I do that using CSS.

Thanks!

Comment: What CSS are you currently using? If you don't specify a `width` then, in Chromium at least, the two elements occupy the same line and take whatever space they need. [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/FV9Gv/1/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about that - the only downside is, that it adds another `<div>`:

#### CSS

```
div.a {
    width:      500px;
    border:     1px solid red;
}

div.a > label {
    float:      left;
}

div.a > div {
    display:    block;
    overflow:   hidden;
    border:     1px solid green;
}

div.a > div > input {
    width:      100%;
}
```

#### HTML

```
<div class="a">
    <label>Some text</label>
    <div>
        <input type="text"/>
    </div> 
</div>
```

#### Demo

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Nc9s8/)